# UITableViewCell Reuse issues with horizontal tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a slightly complicated system that I am having some reuse issues with, wanted to get some feedback.  Basically it is a vertical tableview, and each cell contains another tableview that is rotated 90 degrees, so that each cell scrolls horizontally.  Each horizontal cell is also set up to scroll infinitely with paginated responses from an API.  I am having issues where cells are copying on top of each other when the vertical table is scrolled down.  I have reuse identifiers set up correctly and in each of the horizontal tableviews I am running the following:

```
    - (void)prepareForReuse
{
[_horizontalTableView reloadData];
}
```

If I turn off reusing cells the issue doesn't happen, but the vertical scrolling performance suffers.  I am wondering if its possible that reusing cells in this type of a set up just isnt possible?  Any experience with this is helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: The problematic cells are all coming from the same table view? Other table views? Are you using different reuse IDs for each table? The same one?

Comment: Basically within the vertical tableview there are 4 different types of tableviews that would be displayed in the cells.  Each type has a different reuse identifiers.  The reuse issues are cells in the vertical table being duplicated.  Not all the time, but enough to where its an issue

Comment: Wow - complicated.  Not sure anyone can help without reviewing your code plus a very clear picture of your object graph.

Comment: I figured.  It's a lot of code so I can't post it all here, but thought I'd check to see if anyone had a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct way to solve your issue, but I believe if you use a horizontal scroll view inside each vertical cell, you will have this done faster and with less weird behaviours.  I also believe this is not a standard way, so weird stuff will happen.

All you do is set or extend the content size of the scroll off screen continuously to create an infinite scrolling behaviour. Create views within the scroll view pragmatically to simulate each cell.  Hope this helps.